# Logging frameworks for embedded linux?

Tags: linux, logging, embedded

I need a small, portable framework for logging on embedded linux.  Ideally it would output to a file or a socket, and having some sort of log rotation/compression would also be nice.

So far, I've found a lot of frameworks, but almost all of them have daunting build procedures or require the use of application frameworks (e.g. log4cxx requires the Apache Portable Runtime, which I'd rather not bother with...).

Just looking for something simple and robust, but everything I seem to find is complicated or requires lots of secondary junk just to run.

Suggestions?  (and if the answer is roll my own, that's fine, but...it's be great to avoid that)

Answer (score 10):

Use [syslog(3)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/syslog/) and syslogd from [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/). BusyBox can be very compact when stripped down and doesn't depend on anything other than libc. You can strip out everything you don't want so it is perfectly possible to use it **only** for logging.

We use BusyBox on a number of embedded systems, both Linux and uClinux, and find its logging facilities highly reliable.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with the log4cxx-module but I am using APR on an embedded target running  Linux (it is based on the Atmel AT91SAM926x processor family). It was really simple to configure and compile (more or less ./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi) so I would not be to afraid of going down the log4cxx-path.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider spending some time on a good logging framework, since this is what you are going to use on your embedded Linux. ... and printf ...

I cooked something where I can enable/disable various logging levels per module in runtime.

Did you ever try debugging multithreaded apps on Linux?

Good luck!

Comment: I agree.  In a past project we had developed something similar with runtime control of logging.  This worked out great!  Too bad we weren't able to open source the code.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing very robust logging mechanism in C taking about 1000 code lines (from our code base). 90% of this defines of different sections. This includes different macros `DBG_E DBG_W DBG_TRACE` etc ... and spliting to the section, run time changing of debug level and debug modules (does not include compression just simple print abstraction that can be implemented in different ways file/socket/serial etc...) .
I will estimate that it take about few days to implement. The down side you will spend a few days the up side that you will get something that works for **your** needs and nothing more, i understand that you are working on embedded platform and footprint and memory usage are important, the best and optimized solution will be one you write. We invested those few days ones. and using it across different products/project and adjust/improve with the time past **according to real needs**. Main problem of generic solution that it usually will do sort of what you need and a lot more, this *more* usually just waist of resources.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine that your platform is too small to include log4cxx and APR, neither is a large library, and even the tiniest platform is likely to have space for them.

You could just use syslog, which is provided by the C library - a syslog daemon is provided by busybox (which no doubt, you already use if you're on a really tiny platform). I don't know if busybox's syslogd can log to the network, but it has some level of flexibility. You can do log rotation using shell scripts pretty trivially.

Answer (score 0):

Use **klogd** it reads the kernel log messages(from /proc/kmsg kernel) interface and redirect those messages to appropriate directory. you can use user configurable **syslogd** daemon along with klogd that will redirect kernel messages into appropriate files in /var/log/ directory.
For instance logs related to mail service will be stored in **/var/log/main.log** and logs related to kernel booting process will be stored in **/var/log/boot.log** . User can configure log parsing using syslogd configuration file.

But the use of syslogd may lead to your system performance degradation because for every log messages syslog daemon will do disk operation to store that log into appropriate file

**Log sequence**

**Messages from kernel**
                  ---> **klogd** ( access messages from kernel ring buffer)-->**syslogd** --> /var/log/*